# VB.NET DataGridViewCheckBoxCell Checked value

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I want to get the value from a DataGridViewCheckBoxCell
i have tried various codes

```
DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value = False Then
```

also

```
DataGridView1.rows(i).cells(1).Value = False Then
```

also using ctype and cbool and convert.boolean... When i got into debug, when i move the mouse cursor over the .value, it returns "Nothing"

it is necessary to get the proper boolean value which it wont return...
do i have to change any settings of the checkboxcell at designtime?

Comment: Are you using a binding source for the datagridview datasource? If so what do you bind to?

Comment: Are you set columntype is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn. and check your condition in which event